# Get json value with json key

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json object in javascript

```
 public products: any = {
    "galletas de dinosaurio": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 1",
      "units": 5,
      "addedToList": true
    },

    "galletas de chocolate": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 2",
      "units": 0,
      "addedToList": false
    },

    "galletas de relieve": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 3",
      "units": 10,
      "addedToList": true
    },

    "galletas maria": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 4",
      "units": 17,
      "addedToList": false
    },

    "cerveza alhambra": {
      "name": "Cerveza Alhambra",
      "units": 99,
      "addedToList": true
    },

    "cerveza san miguel": {
      "name": "Cerveza San Miguel",
      "units": 0,
      "addedToList": false
    },

    "cerveza mahou": {
      "name": "Cerveza Mahou",
      "units": 10,
      "addedToList": true
    }
 }
```

I want to have a filter where the user can search a product, so if I type *"galletas"* y wanna to get as result

```
    "galletas de dinosaurio": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 1",
      "units": 5,
      "addedToList": true
    },

    "galletas de chocolate": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 2",
      "units": 0,
      "addedToList": false
    },

    "galletas de relieve": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 3",
      "units": 10,
      "addedToList": true
    },

    "galletas maria": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 4",
      "units": 17,
      "addedToList": false
    }
```

I need to get all the products that contain the string, for example, if I type *"dino"* y want to get all the json objects that contains *"dino"*

```
    "galletas de dinosaurio": {
      "name": "Galletas de prueba 1",
      "units": 5,
      "addedToList": true
    }
```

And I write, for example, *"ffff"* I get nothing in result because no product key contains the words *"ffff"*

Any help is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far.

Comment: Use the `filter()` method on `Object.entries(products)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter based on the names of the products:

```
function getResults(search) {

   return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(products).filter(([name, data]) => name.includes(search)));

}
```

However, considering you are storing basically an array of objects you better store them in an array and put the key (name) in a new field. This structure would make things easier considering every point of view :

```
const products: any[] = [
   {
       "id": "galletas de dinosaurio",
       "name": "Galletas de prueba 1",
       "units": 5,
       "addedToList": true
   }
// ...
]


function search(searchTerm) {
   return products.filter(({id}) => id.includes(seachTerm));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it when I have spare time, but about using an array instead of a json I don't think I can do it, because I need to upload the json to firebase and I think firebase only accepts json, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: arrays are json objects too. I'm pretty sure you can do it

Comment: Then I will give it a try, thanks for the info

Comment: It seems firebase don't like arrays, they say that you can use it but can break with some modifications https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html#:~:text=current%20array%20support.-,Firebase%27s%20Array%20Support,integers%20as%20the%20key%20names.&text=However%2C%20to%20help%20people%20that,in%20Firebase%2C%20when%20you%20call%20.

Comment: Btw, I tried the first code and works well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and filter the result if it passes the condition `key.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())`

```js
const products = {
  "galletas de dinosaurio": {
    name: "Galletas de prueba 1",
    units: 5,
    addedToList: true,
  },

  "galletas de chocolate": {
    name: "Galletas de prueba 2",
    units: 0,
    addedToList: false,
  },

  "galletas de relieve": {
    name: "Galletas de prueba 3",
    units: 10,
    addedToList: true,
  },

  "galletas maria": {
    name: "Galletas de prueba 4",
    units: 17,
    addedToList: false,
  },

  "cerveza alhambra": {
    name: "Cerveza Alhambra",
    units: 99,
    addedToList: true,
  },

  "cerveza san miguel": {
    name: "Cerveza San Miguel",
    units: 0,
    addedToList: false,
  },

  "cerveza mahou": {
    name: "Cerveza Mahou",
    units: 10,
    addedToList: true,
  },
};

function filterProducts(array, search) {
  return Object.keys(array).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (key.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
      acc[key] = array[key];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(filterProducts(products, "galletas"));
console.log(filterProducts(products, "dino"));
```

Comment: You answer works well and is very useful, I can only accept one answer, but you have my upvote, thanks for your help